# there exists a O(n) algorithm for subset sum under certain conditions?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, reference-request, pseudo-polynomial, subset-sum

I was wondering if anybody knows if there is an algorithm for Subset-sum, preferably exact, having a $O(n)$ Time Complexity or near-linear ($n$ = number of elements in the input set)

I remember that some time ago I read a paper (from Psinger? I can't find it again..) stating that there is a linear or near-linear time complexity algorithm when the target value is bounded to a constant.

Can somebody explain to how this algorithm can achieve such TC when the target value is bounded to a constant?

Comment: You are claiming to have a solution for a well-known, difficult open problem. This is [an extraordinary claim requiring extraordinary evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcello_Truzzi#.22Extraordinary_claims.22). You have not provided such so there is not much to talk about. Even if you had, this would not be a good post for SE; it is not our goal here to make broad advances to science in a single post. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/109/) for a related discussion.

Comment: @Raphael I see your point, and I read the guidance you linked and can only agree that this question, although unintentionally, fits what I found there, I should have asked this in other way, so I'm going to keep the comment here for you to read and rephrase the question that was ill-formed. And as per your guidance SE should probably not be the right place for this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution

Comment: You should clarify what "n" is.